# HiveQL How to convert milliseconds in decimal format to mm:ss.SSS

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hql, hiveql

I'm trying to convert decimal timestamp in milliseconds to mm:ss.SSS . The method only works for integers, and the output is not what I desired:

```
select from_unixtime(cast(1911.13/1000 as bigint), 'mm:ss.SSS');
```

1911.13 milliseconds yields the output, 00:01.000, which is not correct, should be 00:01.911

I have tried to convert to double, but received errors

```
select from_unixtime(cast(1911.13/1000 as double), 'mm:ss.SSS');
```

> error:[Code: 10014, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''mm:ss.SSS'': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFFromUnixTime with (double, string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(bigint)  *FUNC*(bigint, string)  *FUNC*(int)  *FUNC*(int, string)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Anything after decimal is milliseconds. So, you can split the string into two parts. Convert before decimal part using from_unixtime and concat it with after decimal part to get the whole data.

```
select cast(from_unixtime(1911, 'mm:ss') as string)|| rpad('.130',4,'0') as col_ms
```

[image: col_ms]

Pls note, millisecond .10 or .1 or .100 means 100 milliseconds, so i used rpad with 0 to pad it.
You can create a generic sql as well.

```
select cast(from_unixtime( cast(substr((cast(x/y) as string) ,1,instr((cast(x/y) as string),'.')) as bigint,'mm:ss') || || rpad(substr((cast(x/y) as string),instr((cast(x/y) as string),'.')),4,'0') as col_ms
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, how do I extract '.130'?  1911.130 is just an example, what should I do if I'm applying to a variable?

Comment: Also I did some research that I need to divide by 1000 to get the right conversion to mm:ss from millisecond.

Comment: I thought you will get the hint. anyways, i updated a generic query to split the string. Pls let me know if that helps.

Comment: so whatever is your output, convert it to a string and then do this. i will change my answer.